# Calculate request and response execution time

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest

Is it possible to calculate request and response time to server ?

For example request was 1 sec. response 2 sec. ?

Generally what takes more to send/receive request or for server to return response ?

Maybe they always take same time and if it lasted for 3 sec. to return data to app, i can 3/2 = 1.5 and think that request and response lasted for 1.5 sec. ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For requesting and getting response, i assume you have created some Method

so this may help

```
NSDate *Start_Time_OF_Method = [NSDate date];

/* ... Do whatever you need to do. for example Your Request/Response kind of coading ... */

NSDate *Finish_Time_OF_Method = [NSDate date];

NSTimeInterval executionTime = [Finish_Time_OF_Method timeIntervalSinceDate:Start_Time_OF_Method];

NSLog(@"executionTime = %f", executionTime);
```

Comment: This is not really what i want. Because i need to know separate time request and response. For example i would get executionTime = 3 and i can't know how much request was or response. Okay i know that this imposable to know without sockets. I want to know which take longer to receive request or return response for server ?

Comment: Actual time is taken In PROCESS which is taking place as Per your Request. For example if you make request for Login with Uname/Pwd..Then the time is taken in backend side to validate the user,perfroming the query and after that it providing response.so indirectly it will make effect on Response.

Comment: Okay but is it possible that my request to server will take longer than response ? I mean not only processing but also network latency

Comment: No..in case of slow server...your request will not take longer time then response..because what you have to make is request. As you make the request the process will start in backend as per the server speed it will provide you response. So request will not take longer time then response.

Comment: Yes this sounds logic. But what if we would talk not about server speed but internet. For example if i make request to web service with data cellular network and some how at request moment it would be slow but on response it will be fast again.

Comment: Then also Request will not take Time longer than the response. As the request part of your coding execute the process will start at back-end and as per Internet / server speed you will get response.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a `NSURLConnection` to make the request to the server, the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` supports quite a lot of delegate methods which can help you here.

Take a look at the documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

When you override those delegate methods I think you can get the information you are looking for. Just make sure you start and stop the timers at the right moment and you will be all set.